# Magento 1.9 Filter by attribute in current category not working

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, filter

I used **layered navigation** for all my **catalog's categories**. In `front-end`, when I `click on a category` and then I try to `filter the products by attribute`, it shows results from all categories. 
**I'd like to show products from the current category, not from all the categories. How to solve?**

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like Magento's standard behaviour. It should only show filtered products from the current category.

I suggest you look into any custom code that might have affect the behaviour.